# ViewPagerIndicator not updating indicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have integrated [CirclePageIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/CirclePageIndicator.java) to viewpager.The issue is that its not changing indicator on changing  views.i.e.the selected circle always remain the first one.Also the colours are not changing.

layout

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/pager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
     android:id="@+id/circles"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_below="@+id/header"
     android:layout_above="@+id/popup_achievement" />
```

Class

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
circlePageIndicator.setBackgroundColor(0xFFCCCCCC);
circlePageIndicator.setRadius(15);
circlePageIndicator.setPageColor(R.color.gray);
circlePageIndicator.setFillColor(R.color.das_color);
circlePageIndicator.setStrokeColor(R.color.dffe_color);
circlePageIndicator.setSnap(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code

circlePageIndicator.setCurrentItem(position);

Comment: u have to call this method before setting the dapater

Comment: so initially i have to write "circlePageIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);" before setting adapter

Comment: If i write  "circlePageIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);" before setting adapter app crashes throeing exception "ViewPager does not have adapter instance."

Comment: soory for miscommunication u have to set it before adding viewpager to it..and if it dsnt work..try jakewhartom viewPagerIndicator library on github..it works like magic...

Comment: Thanks a lott!!! But the PageColor and FillColor is still not changing..Glad if u can help me wid tht

Comment: u r welcome :) i have never tried hands on these two parameters.. i will have to check..